# How to send several Id with Data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here is li which is using data-id to send controller Ids ;

```
 <li><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="mftapproveClass" data-title="@item.Name" data-url="@Url.Action("AssignParticipantToClass")" data-id="@item.Id , @item.CourseId , @item.ClassId"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>Kabul Et</a></li>
```

here is jsthat ı wrote myselft to send 1 id to controller;

```
$('[data-toggle="mftapproveClass"]').click(function () {

    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var courseId = $(this).data("courseId");
    var classId = $(this).data("classId");
    var url = $(this).data("url") + "/" + id + "/" + courseId + "/" + classId;
    var title = $(this).data("title");

    bootbox.confirm({
        title: "İşlem Onayı",
        message: "<center><strong>" + title + "</strong> İşlemi onaylıyor musunuz?</center>",
        buttons: {
            'cancel': {
                label: 'İptal',
                className: 'btn-default'
            },
            'confirm': {
                label: 'Tamam',
                className: 'btn-danger blue'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $("#preLoader").fadeIn('fast');
                $.post(url, function (json) {
                    if (json.IsComplete) {
                        $("#" + id).remove();
                        BSToastr.show("success", "Başarılı", "İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirildi.");
                    }
                    else {
                        BSToastr.show("error", "Hata", "İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi.");
                    }
                    $("#preLoader").fadeOut('fast');
                });
            }
        }
    });


});
```

I was using 1 id but now I needed 3 I amtrying to change but it doesnt work
I am trying to send 3 different IDs to controller but with 1 data id it works but with 3 it didnt work. How this would work to send 3 Ids

here is the output ;

```
POST http://localhost:17458/Panel/Course/AssignParticipantToClass/413%20,%208%20,%202/undefined/undefined 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6x.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6bootbox.confirm.callback @ global.js:210a.buttons.confirm.callback @ bootbox.min.js:6e @ bootbox.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ bootbox.min.js:6x.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5v.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
```

Comment: and what is the markup rendered for this - `data-id="@item.Id , @item.CourseId , @item.ClassId"` can you see in the page source?

Comment: the easiest solution that I can think of is just get advantage of the fact that you receive the ids as a comma separated string. If you know the number and exact position of each Id you use something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/0pc3ok48/ to take the ids and create the url. Also you might want to get rid of the empty spaces (`%20`) as they can be only confusing.

Comment: how can I get rid of this empty spaces ? @Leron

Comment: I think it's more of a cosmetic change. Does the splitting did the trick? However you can get rid of the empty spaces by just removing them from the data attribute making this - `data-id="@item.Id , @item.CourseId , @item.ClassId"` like this - `data-id="@item.Id,@item.CourseId,@item.ClassId"`

Comment: Why not `data-id="@item.Id" data-courseid="@item.CourseId" data-classid="@item.ClassId"`?

Comment: when I use it like that it gets undefined @StephenMuecke

Comment: To access the value, it needs to be `var courseId = $(this).data("courseid");` (lower case)

Comment: yea I did that but still undefined @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then you have made some other error because it works fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yea didnt use lower case now its working like a charm. but it gets like 1 id so I cant get it like public ActionResult AssignParticipantToClass(int? Id , int courseId , int classId)
        {}

Comment: Have you created a custom route definition to handle this? If not then it should be `$.post(url, { id: id, courseId : courseId, classId: classId }, function (json) {` where `url` is just `$(this).data("url")`

Comment: you are the man stephen. love you and thank you. @StephenMuecke I missed that part lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add each property value as a `data-` attribute

```
<a href="#" ... data-id="@item.Id" data-courseid="@item.CourseId" data-ClassId="@item.classid">...</a>
```

and then access them in your script using

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
var courseId = $(this).data("courseid");
var classId = $(this).data("classid");
```

Note that they must be accessed in the `.data()` method using all lowercase. If you inspect the html generated by `data-cOuRseID="someValue"` you will see that it gets converted to lowercase - `data-courseid="someValue"`

Unless you have created a specific route definition for your method, for example

```
url: "Panel/Course/AssignParticipantToClass/{id}/{courseId}/{classId}"
```

Then you need to modify your script to use

```
var url = $(this).data("url"); // don't add the route values
```

and then in the `.post()` method, pass the value using

```
$.post(url, { id: id, courseId : courseId, classId: classId }, function (json) {
```